# WPF- filling color to polyline for wpf toolkit chart

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have created a custom LineSeries graph using a polyline. Below image has plotted two graph ranged from 0-1 and 1.2 to 2 against the date and time. It demo the expected graph output. I have data structure where I will get the data from 0-1 and 1.2 to 2.

My problem is I am not able to fill the color when the point is constantly read 1 till the next drop to 0.

Here is my style

```
<customSeries:StepLineSeries.Style>
<Style TargetType="customSeries:StepLineSeries">
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="customSeries:StepLineSeries">
             <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea" >
                <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="{Binding DataContext.SeriesForeColor, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type customSeries:StepLineSeries}}, 
                      Converter={StaticResource TextToBrushConverter}}">
                      <Polyline DataContext="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type customSeries:StepLineSeries}}}"
                        Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" Stroke="{Binding DataContext.SeriesForeColor}" Fill="White"/>
                 </Border>
              </Canvas>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
</customSeries:StepLineSeries.Style>
```

To Do that I have used Border in the canvas I am filling the color to the border and making Polyline fill to white always. This approach will not work for all the case. Can anyone suggest something better than this to fill the color other than polyline fill

[image]